# Which preposition to use?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition to use?
On Or In.

Sentence:

> I'm working really hard on/in my English.

Comment: People are working [increasingly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hard+on+my+English%2C+hard+in+my+English&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chard%20on%20my%20English%3B%2Cc0) hard on their English.

Comment: Have you done any prior research, like typing both phrases into google to see the kind of results that come up?

Comment: ***in*** is not idiomatically acceptable for this context, but [per this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+%2A+my+French&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwork%20%2A%20my%20French%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwork%20on%20my%20French%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwork%20at%20my%20French%3B%2Cc0), ***at*** is an acceptable alternative to the more common ***on***.

Comment: "in" can be acceptable if "English" means "English lessons", in a school context.

Comment: @JamesK: Only if you also remove the determiner ***my***. As it stands, it's not idiomatic.

Comment: yes that's true

Comment: @FumbleFingers why? can't we say "... in/during my (private) English classes/lessons"?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Sure. You can use "container metaphor" preposition ***in*** if you explicitly include the *real* target noun *(**class, lessons,...**)* - regardless of whether you have a determiner such as ***my***. But if you *don't* specify any additional noun AND you *do* include that determiner, the noun "English" can ***only*** refer to the speakers ***proficiency** (at using English)*, in which case the "container metaphor" ***in*** doesn't work.

Comment: (That's because container metaphors work with ***periods of time***, as well as being suitable when the referent is *literally* a "place" such a classroom.)

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, the preposition that sounds most natural here to me (as a native American English speaker) is ‘on’. ‘work on’ is a relatively common phrasal verb in English vernacular, so independent of any actual grammatical reasoning, the use of ‘on’ here just ‘sounds correct’.

That said, the discussion in the comments is correct. ‘my English’ as a noun phrase (almost) invariably refers to the speaker’s proficiency with the English language, and that is something that cannot be treated like a container, therefore ‘in’ is grammatically incorrect. Furthermore, the lack of an additional noun after ‘my English’ forces it to be a noun phrase itself, which in turn makes the definition obvious.

Where this gets interesting is when you remove the ‘my’ from ‘my English’. The word ‘English’ by itself could refer to the speaker’s proficiency with the English language, or it could be a generic collective noun for the classes taken as part of a course about the English language or as a generic for the course itself. In that case, ‘in’ *could* work, but only if ‘English’ is being used with the generic meaning about a course about the English language.